# Orientation in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, orientation

I am writing the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self checkOrientation];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)receivedRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
    [self checkOrientation];
}  

-(void)checkOrientation
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Right and Left");
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
        // Set x coorinate of views you want to change
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Up or Down");
        // Set x coordinates of views to initial x xoordinates.
    }
}
```

This line

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
```

is not working, and If I will write like

```
self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(-50, -70, 800, 900);
```

then it is changing the axis, but I don't know how it is behaving,

I want to change the view rect change with it will change the orientations, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you going for Notifications for rotations. You can make use of any of these

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation; 

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

- (void)willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

- (void)didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation; 

- (void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

You can find more details in the [reference documents on `UIVIewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @2kV7, I did also same thing in - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation; but again superview could be change, but not the self.view, why>

Comment: Why do you want to change the super views frame here. Adjust the frame for the super and this view in these methods in the super class

Comment: I know it already, but self.view.frame = cgrectmake is working in -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, is not working :-( :-(

Comment: I have UILabel, as the orientation will change, then my labels are not changing rect,

Answer (score 2):

Why are you checking the orientation by making a function by yourselves. Instead, use the function for the UIViewController itself.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{    
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        yourLabel.frame = CGRECTMAKE(10,10,50,50); // for landscape
    }
    else 
    {
        yourLabel.frame = CGRECTMAKE(20,20,50,50); // for portrait
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can you give me the one line code instead of you comments, because self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320); is not working for me?

Comment: you just need to change the frames for the elements of your view and not the View itself. Suppose you wanna change a UIButton's frame then change it like button.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,40,40); View's frame will be converted to 480 x 320 by itself.

Comment: also, one more thing, if there will be a status bar at the top, your view will be having a size of 480 x 300

Comment: self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320) is not working,what should I do now?

Comment: so you want me to change the each label's setFrame individually?

Comment: if you manually wanna change this labels then YES. But there is a good way to change the frames for orientation from the XIB file. Select the View and keep AutoResize SubViews as Selected.

Comment: I dont want to change manually, but how to change frames orientation programmatically, for all frame, help :-(

Comment: I am not using xib, I am writing method that is returning UILabel,

Comment: you'll have to write the frames inside this method only for something which you add programmatically...

Comment: See the link, I have makin two UILabels, with same name, and reinitiazing it, now I can't access the one whose alpha is less, it is an alarm clock app

Comment: so what is the problem in setting up the frame in the method which is written above? I mean its just two lines of the code. Besides, i think that's the only way...

Comment: The issue is the the label whose alpha is not one, is not changing it's position, because I am intilizing the same name of label again with alpha 1, have you understand my problems sir?